# Naughts and crosses in python: scoring not working

Tags: python

I realise that many other people have tried and failed to make naughts and crosses (by looking at the suggested question) but I'm assuming they don't have the same problem as me.

Here is my code:

```
import random, time, sys

raw3 = ["-", "-", "-"]

raw2 = ["-", "-", "-"]

raw1 = ["-", "-", "-"]

def draw():
    str3 = ""
    str2 = ""
    str1 = ""

    for i in raw3:
        str3 = (str3 + i + "   ")
    for i in raw2:
        str2 = (str2 + i + "   ")
    for i in raw1:
        str1 = (str1 + i + "   ")

    str_board = str3+str("\n"*2)+str(str2)+str("\n"*2)+str(str1)
    print(str_board)

def playerX_turn():
    c_choice_in = input("Type the coordinates in the format y/x\n(e.g. 2/1)")
    c_choice_list = list(c_choice_in)
    c_choice_x = int(c_choice_list[0]); c_choice_y = int(c_choice_list[2])
    print(c_choice_x, c_choice_y)

    if c_choice_x == 3 and raw3[c_choice_y - 1] == "-":
        raw3[c_choice_y - 1] = "X"
    elif c_choice_x == 2 and raw2[c_choice_y - 1] == "-":
        raw2[c_choice_y - 1] = "X"
    elif c_choice_x == 1 and raw1[c_choice_y - 1] == "-":
        raw1[c_choice_y - 1]  = "X"

def playerO_turn():
    c_choice_in = input("Type the coordinates in the format y/x\n(e.g. 2/1)")
    c_choice_list = list(c_choice_in)
    c_choice_x = int(c_choice_list[0]); c_choice_y = int(c_choice_list[2])
    print(c_choice_x, c_choice_y)

    if c_choice_x == 3 and raw3[c_choice_y - 1] == "-":
        raw3[c_choice_y - 1] = "O"
    elif c_choice_x == 2 and raw2[c_choice_y - 1] == "-":
        raw2[c_choice_y - 1] = "O"
    elif c_choice_x == 1 and raw1[c_choice_y - 1] == "-":
        raw1[c_choice_y - 1]  = "O"

def check4win():
    winner = None
    if winner == None or winner == False and raw3[0] == "X" or raw3[2] == "X" and raw2[1] == "X" and raw1[0] == "X" or raw1[2] == "X":
        winner = "playerX"

    column_checker = 0
    for i in range(0,3):
        if winner == None or winner == False and raw3[column_checker] == "X" and raw2[column_checker] == "X" and raw1[column_checker] == "X":
            winner = "playerX"
        else:
            column_checker += 1

    if winner == None or winner == False:
        if raw3[0] == "X" and raw3[1] == "X" and raw3[2] == "X":
            winner = "playerX"
        elif raw2[0] == "X" and raw2[1] == "X" and raw2[2] == "X":
            winner = "playerX"
        elif raw1[0] == "X" and raw1[1] == "X" and raw1[2] == "X":
            winner = "playerX"

    ### ### ### ###

    if winner == None or winner == False and raw3[0] == "Y" or raw3[2] == "Y" and raw2[1] == "Y" and raw1[0] == "Y" or raw1[2] == "Y":
        winner = "playerY"

    column_checker = 0
    for i in range(0,3):
        if winner == None or winner == False and raw3[column_checker] == "Y" and raw2[column_checker] == "Y" and raw1[column_checker] == "Y":
            winner = "playerY"
        else:
            column_checker += 1

    if winner == None or winner == False:
        if raw3[0] == "Y" and raw3[1] == "Y" and raw3[2] == "Y":
            winner = "playerY"
        elif raw2[0] == "Y" and raw2[1] == "Y" and raw2[2] == "Y":
            winner = "playerY"
        elif raw1[0] == "Y" and raw1[1] == "Y" and raw1[2] == "Y":
            winner = "playerY"

    ### ### ### ###

    if winner != None or winner != False:
        if winner == "playerX":
            print("X won the game!\n(Sorry, O!)")
        elif winner == "playerY":
            print("Y won the game!\n(Bad luck, X!)")
        sys.exit()

def main():
    game_over = False
    while game_over == False:
        playerX_turn()
        draw()
        check4win()
        playerO_turn()
        draw()
        check4win()

main()
```

So my **first problem** is that this is an example of output from it:

```
>>> 
Type the coordinates in the format y/x
(e.g. 2/1)1,1
1 1
-   -   -   

-   -   -   

X   -   -   
X won the game!
(Sorry, O!)
>>>
```

Which clearly is not correct... 

It's probably a stupid mistake somewhere but I'm too lazy to go looking through it properly, but I've had a brief look through the `check4win()` function, but to no avail.

**Another (less important) thing** is that I have a feeling this code could be made neater... Maybe something with `main()`?

Comment: Honestly, the check4win() function is a mess.  You test to see if one player is the winner several different ways, then do the same for the other player.  As far as I can tell both players are always the winner no matter what.  Which makes no sense.  I suggest you look into multidimensional arrays - having several hard coded arrays for each row means it's hard to iterate over your game data.  A single multidimensional array means you can check all the scenarios for wins in a few lines of code.

Comment: Note that `if winner != None or winner != False:` is always True. Refer to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for tips on negating boolean expressions. Or just use `else`.